# rsync exclude folder contents but still create folder

Tags: linux, deployment, web-deployment, rsync

I have my application:

```
folder1
folder2
cache
     something_cached1
     something_cached2
```

now I want to rsync my project to the server

BUT

if I do

```
 --exclude=cache
```

the folder won't be existing in the server so, I will get an error from the application as it tries to write to a non existent location

Answer (score 8, accepted):

quite simple I see,
just add:

```
--exclude 'cache/*'
```